# get embeded flash to autoPlay

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm really puzzled how this is not working, but the video just wont auto start for some reason, am I doing something wrong? the embedded code is for flash playback

```
<object width="600" height="409">

<param name="movie" value="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf"></param>
<param name="flashvars" value="src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fvideo%2Ftest%2F<?php echo $video;?>"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<param name="autoPlay" value="true"></param>

<embed src="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf"
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" autoPlay="true"
       width="600" height="409" flashvars="src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fvideo%2Ftest%2F<?php echo $video;?>">
</embed>

</object>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put `autoPlay=true` in the `flashvars` param to send this param to swf file:

```
<param name="flashvars" value="src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fvideo%2Ftest%2F<?php echo $video;?>&autoPlay=true"></param>
```

I have tested, it's work.

Remember to change the `flashvars` attribute in `<embed>` tag, too =)

Answer (score 0):

;?>&auto=TR" (not autoPlay only AUTO!)>