# Autoplay flash in ie8 when using a html5 to flash player fallback

Tags: jquery, html, flash

I have a html5 player with flash fallback as follows:

```
<div class="divVideoWrapper">
<div class="divVideo">
<div class="divVideoContainer">
    <div id="videoPlayerChange"  class="video_player">
        <video class="scrPoster" controls="controls" poster="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/testfirstframe.png" >
            <source id="scrVideomp4"  class="scrVideomp4" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/video/bosch/testfeaturevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <source id="scrVideowebm" class="scrVideowebm" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/video/bosch/testfeaturevideo.webm" type="video/webm" />
            <source id="scrVideogg" class="scrVideogg" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/video/bosch/testfeaturevideo.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
            <object id="objFlash" width="352" height="198">
                <param name="movie" value="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf">
                </param>
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
                <embed src="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="330" height="185" flashvars="src=http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/video/bosch/testfeaturevideo.mp4&poster=http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/testfirstframe.png"></embed>
            </object>
        </video>
    <div class="custom_controls">
        <div class="divBigButton">
        <a class="playBig" title="playBig"></a>
        </div>
        <a class="play" title="Play"></a><a class="pause" title="Pause"></a>
        <div class="volumeWrapper">
                <div class="volume">
                        <div class="volume_slider">
                        </div>
                <a class="mute" title="Mute"></a><a class="unmute" title="Unmute"></a>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timer">
        00:00</div>
        <div class="time_slider">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
    $('.video_player').myPlayer();
    });
</script>
```

When a user clicks on a feature a new video is loaded and in HTML5 it will start playing but in flash it won't.  I have tried adding swf&autoStart=true" in the param and autoplay ="yes" and autostart = "true" in the embed part but these don t seem to work - I'm testing it in ie8 as this is the browser that falls back to flash.

Jquery script which changes the video

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(document).on("click", ".featureLogoText", function () {


                var media = $(this).attr('media');
                var mediamp4 = media + "mp4";
                var mediawebm = media + "webm";
                var mediaogv = media + "ogv";
                var newPoster = $(this).attr('data-poster');

                var html = ' <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf\"></param><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param><param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"></param><embed src=\"http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" width=\"330\" height=\"185\" autoplay =\"true\" flashvars=\"src=' + mediamp4 + '&poster=' + newPoster + '\"></embed>';

                $("#objFlash").html("");
                $("#objFlash").append(html);



                var displayText = $(this).text();

                $(".divBottomRight .nowPlaying").text("Now Playing: ");
                $(".divBottomRight .nowPlayFeature").text(displayText);

                var number = $(this).attr('data-number');


            });
        });
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer b clicking on one of the links to the left!

[get embeded flash to autoPlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426747/get-embeded-flash-to-autoplay?rq=1)

so basically i replaced my &poster = in the embed in the flashvars with &autoPlay=true"