# Play/Pause iFrame using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, video, controls, playback

Is there a way to play or pause an iFrame video? It is not a youtube or vimeo video, so there is no api for me to reference.

For some background, I am pulling this video from an api that only returns their videos as flash objects. Since flash doesn't seem to play on any mobile devices, I had to pull a src attribute and dynamically put it into an iframe. This seems to be working fine, but I need a way to auto play the video when the page loads. My best guess is to call a JS function when the document loads, but Im not sure how to make the thing play.

Here is a video in object format:

```
<object height="344" width="434">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <param name="movie" value="http://embed.redtube.com/player/?id=260891&style=redtube">
    <param name="FlashVars" value="id=260891&style=redtube&autostart=true">
    <embed src="http://embed.redtube.com/player/?id=260891&style=redtube" 
        allowfullscreen="true" 
        AllowScriptAccess="always" 
        flashvars="autostart=true" 
        pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" 
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
        height="344" width="434" />
</object>
```

This flash video does not play on a mobile device though.
I can pull the src attribute above in php, and plug it into an iframe like below, which should play on any device.

```
<iframe id="myMovie" src=<?php echo $src;?> width="750" height="420" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

This works fine and the video shows up and plays on my local machine, but will not auto play, which is the desired functionality.

So if there is a better way to achieve the desired functionality on all devices please let me know. If anyone can help me auto play the iframe, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Providing some code would make it easier to understand what you want, depending on how you're doing it, something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426747/get-embeded-flash-to-autoplay) may help

Comment: I can get the flash object to auto play fine like in the answer you provided, but that video is not supported on most mobile devices, from what I understand.

Comment: I edited my question to now include all the code Im working with