# How do I get this flash embed code to auto play?

Tags: flash

How do I get this to autoplay?  What am I missing?

```
<object width="720" height="405" id="flashObj" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,47,0">

<param name="autoStart" value="true" />

<param name="movie" value="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&amp;isUI=1">

<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">

<param name="flashVars" value="playerID=1532807519001&amp;@videoPlayer=938647062001&amp;playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAuO09Aok~,b8rN8q_RXZltqbXswVt3zVzVwa3Da8Zo&amp;domain=embed&amp;dynamicStreaming=true&amp;autoPlay=true">

<param name="base" value="http://admin.brightcove.com">

<param name="seamlesstabbing" value="false">

<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">

<param name="swLiveConnect" value="true">

<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">

<embed name="flashObj" width="720" height="405" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" src="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&amp;isUI=1&amp;autoPlay=true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" swliveconnect="true" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" seamlesstabbing="false" base="http://admin.brightcove.com" autoplay="true" flashvars="playerID=1532807519001&amp;@videoPlayer=938647062001&amp;playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAuO09Aok~,b8rN8q_RXZltqbXswVt3zVzVwa3Da8Zo&amp;domain=embed&amp;dynamicStreaming=true&amp;autoPlay=true;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the flashvars parameter like this instead:

```
<param name="flashVars" value="playerID=1532807519001&amp;@videoPlayer=938647062001&amp;playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAuO09Aok~,b8rN8q_RXZltqbXswVt3zVzVwa3Da8Zo&amp;domain=embed&amp;dynamicStreaming=true&amp;?>&autoPlay=true">
```

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426747/get-embeded-flash-to-autoplay) if still unsure as its the same problem.