# How do I make this flash file autplay?

Tags: html, object, flash, embed

Check out this flash file loaded here: http://www.gameprehacks.com/ad.html

or view code below

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="336" height="280" 
data="http://buxle.com/buxle-starsbanner.swf" >
<param name="play" value="true" />
<param name="movie" value="http://buxle.com/buxle-starsbanner.swf" />
<param name="wmode" value="direct" />
<param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://buxle.com/buxle-starsbanner.swf" width="336" height="280" wmode="direct" play="true" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

It works in Internet Explorer as it should, but in Chrome, the file has a play button. I need this to autoplay in Chrome. How can I achieve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Just affix `autoplay` to your `<video>` tag. `<video autoplay>`. In XHTML (which forbids minification), this must be written as `<video autoplay="autoplay">`.

Comment: I've tried adding all sorts of autoplay tags. Nothing seems to be working. Also, this is not a video, this is a flash file object.

Comment: Your URL is far too suspicious for me to click on (it would help to actually include your code in the question itself in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14427985/2341603) is probably the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I've actually tried that, no help. i've edited my post to include the raw html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome does not auto-play Flash-based adverts. It has been like this for a long time.
 See [**this article**](https://arstechnica.co.uk/information-technology/2015/08/google-chrome-will-block-auto-playing-flash-ads-from-september-1/) from 2015 announcing the plan for Google's browser.

Anyway to avoid the "Play" icon :

- Have both the SWF file and also the HTML file together in same location.
- or... Set a high width and height to avoid appearing like a banner/advert.

Also try to use (secure) `https://` links whenever possible if your site is also on HTTPS server.

Try this version of your code using increased width/height and also HTTPS-based URL. This worked for me (but you can try with HTTP links) :

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="480" height="400" 
data="https://buxle.com/buxle-starsbanner.swf" >
<param name="play" value="true" />
<param name="movie" value="https://buxle.com/buxle-starsbanner.swf" />
<param name="wmode" value="direct" />
<param name="pluginspage" value="https://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="https://buxle.com/buxle-starsbanner.swf" width="336" height="280" wmode="direct" play="true" pluginspage="https://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```